# two division put the details in inner div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 2 divisoin

```html
<div id="details">
    <div id="feature">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to put the content using `$("#details").html(content);` (it is working correctly) like that way i need to put the content inside feature div i am using following way:

```js
 $("#details #feature").html(content);
```

but it is not working..how to solve?

Comment: You should use `$("#details").find("#feature").html(content);`

Comment: sherin are you using both the code together I mean `$("#details").html(content);` and `$("#details #feature").html(content);` simultaneously ?

Comment: yes..,both are using simultaneously

Comment: @SHERINAS : lol then you should look **Morris Janatzek** answer

Comment: there's no reason to downvote this question :|

Comment: I updated my answer and added an example.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `$("#details").html(content);` you override the content of the div. So you're inner div with the id `feature` gets removed. Maybe you use `$("#details").prepend(content);` or you add another div for the main content and replace that content.

Look here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/morrisjdev/s9u7rfcu/

Comment: User is not overriding the data. OP states that `$("#details").html(cont‌​ent);` is working so why not `$("#details #feature").html(cont‌​ent);` ?

Comment: @YoYo Thank you :) when he first uses `$("#details").html(cont‌​ent);` and than the next command `#feature` will not exist.

Comment: i am also tried  $("#details").append(content) it is not getting

Comment: @SHERINAS : then check your **content** value

Answer (score 0):

`ID` is a unique attribute so you can directly use id like below.

```js
$(function() {
  var content = "Some text here";
  $('#feature').html(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="details">
  <div id="feature">
  </div>
</div>
```

**OR**

```js
$(function() {
  var content = "Some text here";
  $('#details').find('#feature').html(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="details">
  <div id="feature">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes tried but it is not getting.....is any other syntax for this like $("#details #feature").html(content);

Comment: can you explain why not the selector which OP used

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var htmldetail ="Hello! I am Here";
      var details = $("#details").html(htmldetail);
      $("#userfeature").html(details);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="details">
  <div id="userfeature">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second is `#feature` and not `#userfeature`. And also add the jQuery Library as well. You can replace test with content variable.

```js
$("#feature").html("test");
```

```html
<div id="details">
 <div id="feature">
  </div>
           </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And also remember Id is unique and hence no need to mention its parent.

Run the following snippet and you can get the output.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way..Go Through this**

HTML

```
<div id="details">
   <div id="feature">
   </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      var content="contain sample data";
    //    $("#details").html(content); if you wrote like this,
 this will replace all content, so the inner div will be replaced
        $("#details").append(content); // outer div
        $("#feature").html(content);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use css-like selector method:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#details > #feature').html('Hello <strong>World!!!</strong>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="details">
    <div id="feature">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a plunk for it and it is working.

Try including the action inside

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    var content = 'Hey there';
    $("#details #feature").html(content);
});
```

Plunk :- http://plnkr.co/edit/63GsIoGmprnKs7oe77cF?p=preview